# Lost Password of my site, how to reset wordpress password?

Tags: plugins, login, password, static-website, remote-login

I have a site (https://threatsfixguide.com/) that is hosted on WordPress. I had the login credentials saved in the browser. I was using Google Chrome browser. Somehow while clearing the cache from the browser I deleted the saved password, and now I can log in to my site. Is there a way to reset WordPress password???

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely! Simply go to https://threatsfixguide.com/wp-admin/, click on the **Lost your password?** link, and follow the steps. The reset password link will be sent to the email address associated with your WordPress admin user. Make sure you remember the email address you used for your WordPress admin account.

Answer (score 0):

If the "Lost Your Password" link doesn't work, I assume you are the website's owner.

- You must have access to your WordPress database.
- Access your WordPress, you can either do it from your hosting provider dashboard or if you are hosting your database. Navigate to the "users" table. The name of the table would be "someprefix_users".
- Access this table, and find your user. You would need to edit the password column. Since passwords are stored as "HASH" you would need to first create an MD5 hash of your password and then update the password column. To create an MD5 hash of your password you can use this [LINK](https://www.md5hashgenerator.com/). Once you update the value of the password field. Navigate to your WordPress site using {Wordpress_site_url}/wp-admin and log in using the updated password.